# Perforce command to set changelist description

Tags: perforce

I'm looking for the Perforce command to update a non-default changelist's description either on creation, after creation, or on submit.  You can set the description on submit using `p4 submit <description>` only for the default changelist.  And when you try something like `p4 change <changelistnumber> -i <description>`, you're forced to edit then save a text file.  I'm looking for something like this (but that works, obviously):

```
p4 change -c <changelistnumber> -d <description>
```

Answer (score 2):

To provide the description of a numbered changelist, 'p4 change -i' is the way you want to go.

You don't actually have to bring up your editor: just prepare a text file ahead of time with the changelist spec as you want it, including your modified description, and then run 'p4 change -i NNN < mySpecFile.txt'.

Run 'p4 change -o >/tmp/change.txt' or 'p4 help change' to see the overall format of the changelist spec.

If you're planning to build a tool that does this, do you have a preferred scripting language (Perl/Ruby/Python/etc.)? If so, there are very elegant integrations of the Perforce command set into each of those scripting languages, which make this sort of task very straightforward.

Comment: I'm writing this with C#. I'm also creating the change list on the fly shortly before I submit so it doesn't seem like a pre-existing text file will work.

Comment: Perhaps you can use this approach, then: http://forums.perforce.com/index.php?/topic/2568-p4apinet-update-changelist-description/#entry10162

Comment: I appreciate the link, but P4API.NET is an unusable abomination.  I'll just skip updating the description.

Comment: Great technique..!! Thanks @BryanPendleton

Answer (score 1):

You can also use 'p4 change -u '. It will open a text editor from which you can update your description.

Documentation: https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_change.html?Highlight=p4%20change

I know -u option is available on release 2015 and newer. I don't know about older versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without invoking any editor, using the `--field` global Perforce option. It is documented in `p4 help undoc`:

> ```
> p4 --field Field=replacement_text
> p4 --field Field+=extra_text
>     Modify the contents of a spec returned by p4 [specname] -o.  The
>     modified spec can be piped directly to another command that expects
>     a formatted spec, e.g. p4 [specname] -i.
> ```

So if you want to update the description of an existing changelist, and know what you want the description to be, you can run:

```
p4 --field 'Description=Add the Widget to the frobulator' change -o 12345 | p4 change -u -i
```